# iBeacon content management system

Tags: ios7, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I have developed a set of iBeacons and it shows the UUID, Major and Minor values on the iBeacon locate app from Google Play. The next step is fetching the data from the cloud. I am aware that Kontakt, Estimote, GeLo etc offer CMS for the beacons bought from them.

I am looking for an effective iBeacon Management platform where i can fetch and manage data from the cloud on entering proximity. Also, would setting up own cloud management a good idea? Please suggest the best approach. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check out our iBeacon Interaction Management Platform: [Pushmote](https://pushmote.com). There is free package, Basic package, which includes all the following features monthly for each app:

- 10.000 Interactions
- 1M Geo-fencing enabled Push Notifications
- 10.000 Passbooks
- Detailed analytics with iBeacon Heat Maps
- Audience Segmentation
- 20GB CDN Storage
- User Timelines

You can request beta invitation and start using it. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my company's [ProximityKit](http://www.proximitykit.com/) service.  It lets you set up key/value pairs for all your iBeacons managed in the cloud, and syncs them automatically to devices with your app installed.  It offers iOS and Android SDKs.

A build vs. buy decision often comes down to a few factors:

CONs to building your own:

- I takes time and money to develop.
- It takes time and money to bug fix and maintain your own solution.
- You have to learn the potentially painful lessons of building your own that other folks have already figured out.

PROs to building your own:

- You get to customize it to be exactly what you want.

Full disclosure:  I am Chief Engineer at Radius Networks.

Comment: Hi David, Been following a lot of blogs from Radius Networks, glad to hear from you! Have just signed up for developer Portal. Will keep you posted?

Comment: Found a codebase for android app for museums [here](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/museum-guide-android/tree/master/app) . Incidentally i have a demo with a local museum. Hope this really works out. Amen!